# error: video system not initialized ; Why is pygame.init() not working?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()


wn = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit():
            pygame.QUIT()
            sys.exit()

    
    pygame.display.update()
    wn.fill((255,255,255))
    pygame.display.flip(bgcolor)
```

Comment: Are you saying you get an error from `pygame.init()`?  Or are you saying it gets no error but just doesn't work?  How are you running this?

Comment: The quit check is also invalid. Change `if event.type == pygame.QUIT():` to `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:` and remove the `pygame.QUIT()` line.

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) is a function and uninitialize all PyGame modules. When you do

> ```py
> if event.type == pygame.quit():
> ```

the function is called and all PyGame modules are uninitialized.

The *type* attribute of [`pygame.event.Event()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object indicates the type of event. You need to compare the event type to the enumeration constant that identifies the event. The *quit* event is identified by `pygame.QUIT` (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module):

Hence, you have to compete with `pygame.QUIT` instead of `pygame.quit()`:

<s>`if event.type == pygame.quit():`</s>

```py
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```